# What is the word that means the area of work where someone has experience and knowledge?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

What is the word that means the area of work where someone has experience and knowledge?

It should be similar to *major*, but *major* doesn't include the work/training expertise that you may have acquired beyond college.

Comment: *Expertise*? Also in common business use is SME (pronounced smee) or *subject matter expert*.

Comment: Speciality/specialty // forte // strong point // strength // long suit //// thing //// field

Comment: Best to include a sample sentence with such questions so answerers can get a sense of the degree of formality that might be required.   Other synonyms in a more casual register could be "area" and "bailiwick".

Comment: Thanks for the answers and hyperlink of similar questions.